# Can a nilpotent element be an idempotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $(R, +, \times, 0, 1)$ is a ring with unity and $a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is a non-zero nilpotent element. Can it be an idempotent?

We call $a$ nilpotent if $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $a^n = 0$. We call $a$ idempotent, if $a^2 = a$.

Comment: Do you knw the definitions of nilpotent and of idempotent? What happens if you try to combine them?

Comment: Unless zero is regarded as nilpotent.

Comment: Please come with definitions and also mention nonzero nilpotent elements.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3478373/edit) to add your thoughts.

Comment: Suppose $x^2=x$. What can you say about $x^3$?

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is idempotent, then $p^2=p.$ Show by induction , that $p^n=p$ for all $n \in \mathbb N, n \ge 1.$

What can you conclude, if $p$ is nilpotent ?